# Is it possible to upgrade directly from Symfony 2.0 to Symfony 2.3?

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible to directly upgrade Symfony 2.0.10 to Symfony 2.3? (Without a step by step procedure like Symfony 2.0 to 2.1 and 2.1 to 2.2).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's possible. But that means you have to read all upgrade files ([`UPGRADE-2.1.md`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md), [`UPGRADE-2.2.md`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.2.md), [`UPGRADE-2.3.md`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.3.md)) to be sure all your code works. There are a lot of BC breaks between 2.0 and 2.3.

EDIT: Don't forget to see if your third party bundles support 2.3.